# how to get my current_location correctly

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

Hi I have been trying to get the `current location` with  fql from Graph API Explorer, but I got the following result:

```
  {
      "data": [
        {
          "current_location": null
        }
      ]
    }
```

I have made the following consult:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT%20current_location%20FROM%20user%20WHERE%20uid=MYUID&access_token=MYACCESSTOKEN
```

It’s important to let you know that the `access token` I generate is made with the `user_hometown` and `user_location` permits needed. I wish to know how to do it properly.
Thanks!
Alberto

Answer (score 2):

`user_hometown` gives you access to the field `hometown_location`. Not much help here.

`user_location` permission gives you access to the field `current_location`.  I was able to pull my current location out correctly.  This is the setting found on your Living section of your user (http://www.facebook.com/USERNAME/info).  I changed my current city, went back to the FQL and checked, and sure enough your FQL statement in your question tracked it.

You might be confusing current_location with last checkin location.